# colorRamp returns 0

Tags: r, colors, color-palette

I'm trying to plot lines and color the lines based on the probability of that connection.  Given a vector of probabilities, I use:

```
colfunc <- colorRamp(c("white", "red"))
colors <- colfunc(probs)
```

colors is then an nx3 matrix of rgb values.  However, colfunc quite often returns a 0 value, so when i attempt to plot using these colors, R complains

```
Error in col2rgb(colors) : numerical color values must be positive
```

Is there an error in the way I am defining my color function?

Answer (score 1):

Your function works fine, I think, but it doesn't return colors you can use with `plot`, because `plot` wants a color, not RGB values in a matrix.

There's probably a better way, but you can simply covert the matrix:

```
probs <- runif(10)
colors <- colfunc(probs)
my_col = apply(colors, MARGIN = 1,  function(x) rgb(x[1]/255, x[2]/255, x[3]/255))

plot(1:10, 1:10, col = my_col) # should work fine
```

or you could just wrap your function

```
better_colfunc <- function(x, ramp = colorRamp(c("white", "red"))) {
   colors <- ramp(x)
   colors = apply(colors, MARGIN = 1,  function(x) rgb(x[1]/255, x[2]/255, x[3]/255))
   return(colors)
}

plot(1:10, 1:10, col = better_colfunc(probs, ramp = colfunc))
```

As for "colfunc quite often returns a 0 value", and other issues, you'll need to share both some data (what do your `probs` look like?) as well as perhaps the actual plotting code. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on making reproducible questions.

Answer (score -1):

I am a bit confused what you are trying to do...the col2rgb function returns rgb values, so if you already have those then what do you want?

Or if you want rgb, why not use:

```
col2rgb(c("white", "red"))
```